# VSCode ANTLR4 Plugin: Export Call Graph to JSON?

Tags: visual-studio-code, antlr4

The `vscode-antlr4` plugin for VisualStudio Code has a nice call-graph feature which visualizes (as a dendrogram) how grammar (and lexer) rules interact. You can save the graphic as SVG.

Is there a way to export the information as JSON? I wouldn't mind going into the plugin's code to find a way to do it.

My aim is to create reachability graphs for individual rules, i.e. graphs that show from which other rules a particular rule can be reached (transitively). The "calls" and "is-called" information from the call-graph feature would be a nice starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data for the call graph comes from a source context instance (for each grammar file there's a single source context to manage all details for it). See the function [`getReferenceGraph`](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/backend/SourceContext.ts#L571), which collects the relations into a map object. You can use that object to generate a JSON object from it. Or you create another function, taking this one as template, to generate the JSON directly, without the overhead required for the UI.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. In the source context instance, would references to other g4 files (via `import`, `tokenVocab`, ...) already be resolved, or would I have to take care of them myself?

Comment: That's done via the symbol table which allows lookups to referenced tables (and does this lookup automatically).